# Why is the joint probability measure of two random variables not defined on the product of their sample spaces?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X, Y$ be random variables defined on a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. The random vector $(X, Y)$ is defined as the function $$(X, Y): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2, (X, Y)(\omega) \mapsto (X(\omega), Y(\omega)).$$

My question is this: why is the random vector not instead defined on the product of the measure spaces:

$$(X, Y): \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2?$$

For example, if I take two iid Bernoulli random variables, then the random vector that they form is a random variable that can only take two values: $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$. It seems to me that the random vector and its corresponding joint distribution should instead be defined on the product of the sample spaces.

Comment: What would the definition be then? The point of being a joint distribution is that you look at values of the variables for the same outcome in the universe. If you look at X and Y for different outcomes, it can't be "joint" anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an important distinction between *identical* random variables (where $X = Y$) and *identically distributed* random variables.
In the first case, $X$ and $Y$ really are the same function on $\Omega,$
so $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ always.
But in the second case, $X$ and $Y$ may be quite different functions on $\Omega.$

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are both Bernoulli variables, "identically distributed" means that the set of $\omega$ for which $X(\omega) = 1$ has exactly the same probability measure as the set of $\omega$ for which $Y(\omega) = 1.$
But it could be the case that
$$P((X,Y)=(1,0)) = P((X,Y)=(0,1)) = P((X,Y)=(0,0)) = \frac13.$$
That is, $X=1$ one-third of the time and $Y=1$ one-third of the time,
but never at the same time.

This allows us to construct identically distributed random variables
that are **not** independent.
It seems to me that would be very hard to do if each variable had to act on its own individual copy of $\Omega.$
How would you model correlations between identically-distributed variables?

The usual definition also allows us to define a Bernoulli variable $X$ such that
$P(X=0) = P(X=1) = \frac12$ and a second variable $Y = 1 - X,$
and then say that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.
This would be impossible if identically-distributed variables had to be the same function of $\Omega.$

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified a lot for me. But, I am still confused about the initial example I gave, where the sample space is the result of a coin toss: $\Omega = {H, T}.$ Even if $X,Y$ are different functions, the image of the random vector $(X, Y)$ can only have two elements since our sample space only has two elements.

Comment: The sample space $\Omega$ is not generally the same as the list of outcomes. Yes, you can write $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ if you have one coin that you intend to toss just once and never toss it again. But as you yourself have shown, this is not a suitable sample space when you want to toss the coin again. You need a different sample space. Personally, I prefer not to even consider how my sample space looks or what are the specific names of its elements. I only care that subsets of those elements exist that cause my random variables to take the values they need with the joint distribution they need.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, if I take two iid Bernoulli random variables, then the random vector that they form is a random variable that can only take two values: (0,0) and (1,1). It seems to me that the random vector and its corresponding joint distribution should instead be defined on the product of the sample spaces.

The sample space is the set of *all possible outcomes*.  We may map *this* set of outcomes to various random variables, such as the random pair, the individual members, or their sum.  Also, any probability measure.
$$\begin{align}\langle X,Y\rangle &: \Omega\mapsto\{0,1\}^2\\X &: \Omega\mapsto\{0,1\}\\Y &: \Omega\mapsto\{0,1\}\\X+Y&:\Omega\mapsto \{0,1,2\}\\\Bbb P&:\Omega\mapsto[0..1]\end{align}$$

So, we are measuring the *same set of outcomes* to different images.  $X$ and $Y$ do not have different pre-images.

---

Often, for convenience, we conflate the sample space with a measured *image* that gathers *the most information* in which we're interested in identifying outcomes; and discards irrelevant data.

Indeed, this is typically a Cartesian product, such as $\{\langle 0,0\rangle, \langle 0,1\rangle, \langle 1,0\rangle, \langle 1,1\rangle\}$ .

But we do not have to do that.

---

**Another approach.**

We may take as a sample set the outcomes of a die roll (which is unbiassed and six-sided). $$\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

Let $X$ indicate "the result is even", and $Y$ indicate "the result is prime".  So $$\begin{align}X(\omega)&=\begin{cases}1&:& \omega\in\{2,4,6\}\\0&:&\omega\in\{1,3,5\}\end{cases}\\Y(\omega)&=\begin{cases}1&:& \omega\in\{2,3,5\}\\0&:&\omega\in\{1,4,6\}\end{cases}\\\langle X, Y\rangle(\omega)&=\begin{cases}\langle 1,1\rangle&:&\omega\in\{2\}\\\langle 1, 0\rangle&:&\omega \in\{4,6\}\\\langle 0,1\rangle &:&\omega\in\{3,5\}\\\langle 0,0\rangle &:& \omega\in \{1\}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Then we have that $$\begin{align}X&:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\mapsto\{0,1\}\\Y&:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\mapsto\{0,1\}\\\langle X,Y\rangle &: \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\mapsto\{0,1\}^2\end{align}$$